# Client Profile Preview - Whats included and excluded

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-client-profile

My understanding of the client profile preview is that it's a stripped down version of .NET focusing on fulfiling the needs of client applications.

However it would be useful to know what is included and excluded from this? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of included assemblies from [BCL Team Blog @ MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2008/05/21/net-framework-client-profile-justin-van-patten.aspx):

BCL, "Core FX," and LINQ

```
* CustomMarshalers
* ISymWrapper
* mscorlib
* sysglobl
* System
* System.AddIn
* System.AddIn.Contract
* System.Configuration
* System.Configuration.Install
* System.Core
* System.Security
```

Visual Basic and Visual C++ Language Support

```
* Microsoft.VisualBasic
* Microsoft.VisualC
```

XML

```
* System.Xml
* System.Xml.Linq
```

Windows Forms

```
* Accessibility
* System.Drawing
* System.Windows.Forms
```

WPF

```
* PresentationCore
* PresentationFramework
* PresentationFramework.Aero
* PresentationFramework.Classic
* PresentationFramework.Luna
* PresentationFramework.Royale
* PresentationUI
* ReachFramework
* System.Printing
* System.Windows.Presentation
* UIAutomationClient
* UIAutomationClientsideProviders
* UIAutomationProvider
* UIAutomationTypes
* WindowsBase
* WindowsFormsIntegration
```

ClickOnce

```
* System.Deployment
```

WCF, Web Services, Remoting, and Serialization

```
* System.IdentityModel
* System.Runtime.Remoting
* System.Runtime.Serialization
* System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap
* System.ServiceModel
* System.ServiceModel.Web
* System.ServiceModel.Install
* System.Transactions
* System.Web.Services
```

Data Access

```
* System.Data
* System.Data.SqlXml
* System.Data.DataSetExtensions
* System.Data.Services.Client
```

Peer to Peer

```
* System.Net
```

Active Directory and Enterprise Services

```
* System.DirectoryServices
* System.EnterpriseServices
```